# Ruta update Api Laravel no actualiza

Tags: laravel, api

Tengo una tabla "indicadors" en mi base de datos y un modelo "Indicador".

En mi IndicadorController así tengo el método update:

```
public function update(UpdateIndicadorRequest $request, Indicador $indicador)
    {
        $indicador->update($request->validated());
        return response()->json("Indicador Actualizado");
    }
```

Mientras que así tengo la ruta en api.php:

```
Route::put('/indicadores/{id}', [IndicadorController::class, 'update']);
```

Luego pongo la ruta en Postman y me dice que actualizó, pero en realidad no actualiza nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué pudo salir mal?

Comment: Que hay en UpdateIndicadorRequest? Como definiste la propiedad $fillable del modelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema podría estar relacionado con la forma en que se está pasando el parámetro de ruta id a la función update() en el controlador. En lugar de recibir un objeto Indicador como se espera, el controlador está recibiendo un valor de id que debería usarse para buscar el objeto Indicador correspondiente en la base de datos.

Para corregir este problema, actualiza la ruta en api.php para pasar el parámetro de ruta id y usarlo para buscar el objeto Indicador antes de llamar al método update() del modelo. La ruta debería verse así:

```
Route::put('/indicadores/{id}', [IndicadorController::class, 'update']);
```

Luego, actualiza el método update() en el controlador para buscar el objeto Indicador correspondiente utilizando el id pasado a la ruta y luego llamar al método update() en ese objeto. El código del controlador debería verse así:

```
public function update(UpdateIndicadorRequest $request, $id)
{
    $indicador = Indicador::findOrFail($id);
    $indicador->update($request->validated());
    return response()->json("Indicador Actualizado");
}
```

De esta forma, deberías poder actualizar correctamente el objeto Indicador en la base de datos cuando se llama a la ruta en Postman.

Comment: ¡Funcionó!

Había que hacerlo como dices tú, buscando la id.

$indicador = Indicador::findOrFail($id);